# Class with global variables in Web Application Project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I'm trying to migrate from the Web Site Project style
to use the Web Application Project instead.

The App_Code folder is missing, and I have read
the reasons why, about compilation to .dll's
and so, and why I should not include and reference both
classes and dll's. That is fine. It is recommended that 
I move my .vb classes from the App_Code or simply
rename the folder to "CodeFolder". I have now 
done that.

But I am used to have a class named Globals.vb
in the App_Code folder with global variables and functions
which I can access throughout my entire site without
instatiation.

My Globals.vb could for example look like:

```
Public Class Globals
   Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
         Public Shared Path As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebPath")
         Public Shared strSql as String

         Public Shared Function ConvertVBLineBreaksToHTML(Byval s as String) as string
              'Code here
         End Function
 End Class
```

And so on. How do I accomplish that with a WAP? And also, what about
.xsd datasets in my previous App_Code folder which also were accessible
from anywhere?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need App_code in a Web application style. You can reference other class as long as you have the correct namespace reference.

If you want it in an organized way just put your code in different folders then create different namespace with each folder, so you can keep track the purpose/scope of each class and referenced in your project accordingly.

So let say in the helper folder, you have a webhelper.cs as follows

```
namespace helper
{
    //code such as extension method and stuff..
}
```

and you have a modules folder with a sitemodule.cs as follows

```
namespace modules
{
    // code to handle/manage site module
}
```

Then in your code behind of your web page just reference these namespace to use them:

```
using helper;
using modules;

public class testpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  //....
}
```

For the strongly typed dataset, you can use the following command line to convert it to a class first:

```
xsd.exe yourdataset.xsd /dataset
```

You need to run it from the .net sdk tool. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi HOKBONG - thank you, I'll try that tomorrow :-) Do you know about where to .xsd-datasets now, where the App_Code is excluded?

Comment: I add the .xsd part to the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Hi - thanks for the code. It is working creating namespaces as you show, but I can only reference it when I place the webhelper.cs in App_Code. If I remove it to let's say CodeFolder it won't recognize it. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you can show sample of your code so I can take a look ;)